# UIButton Configuration Line Break Mode Not Working

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel, line-breaks

I know there are a few SO posts about this, but none are working...

I am just trying to get my custom UIButton subclass using the `UIButton.Configuration` method to **force my title label to stay 1 line, without changing the button frame.**

I keep getting the right button shown below...

[image]

What can I do?? Here is how I am setting up by button..

```
init(withTitle title: String, ... <more custom params> ...) {

    // ...

    super.init(frame: .zero)

    var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    config.title = title

    titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
                
    configurationUpdateHandler = { button in

        // ... here I handle colorizing elements for different button states /

    }

}
```

---

I understand I can accomplish the text clipping by using a standard `let button = UIButton(type: .custom)`, and set the `titleLabel` line properties. This is not a solution - the customization offered with the configuration are not available otherwise.

Comment: I have the same issue and I don't find any solution yet. It seems that using UIButton.Configuration breaks all changes on titleLabel (that will have no effects). So if starting using UIButton.Configuration force to use it for all your settings, but I've not found a property to limit the number of lines. That's a very strange behavior

Answer (score 2):

One big issue with your code is that you create the `UIButton.Configuration` but you never make use of it. Here's an updated version of your custom `init` for your custom `UIButton` subclass that properly sets up and uses a `UIButton.Configuration`.

```swift
class MyButton: UIButton {
    convenience init(withTitle title: String, image: String) {
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.title = title
        config.titleLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        config.image = UIImage(systemName: image)

        self.init(configuration: config)

        configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
            // ... here I handle colorizing elements for different button states
        }
    }
}
```

By making the custom `init` a `convenience` init, you can call the `init(configuration:)` convenience init.

Add that class and the following code to an iOS Swift Playground:

```swift
let btn = MyButton(withTitle: "This is some sample text that should CLIP", image: "calendar")
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
```

and you get the following result:

[image]

Obviously you need to adjust this sample code with your additional `init` parameters and button configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proud of it.

```swift
button.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
    if let titleLabel = button.titleLabel {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Working example of button with long text]

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Xcode 14.3 you can specify line break mode via [`UIButton.Configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/4130647-titlelinebreakmode) object as:

```swift
var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
config.titleLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
myButton.config = config
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode 14.3. `UIButton.Configuration` and `titleLineBreakMode` were added in iOS 15 (which was added in Xcode 13).

Comment: One might argue that the "real" answer to the question is: don't use button configuration-style types (plain, filled, etc.). Just go right on using the system or custom type, and then, presto, the `titleLabel` springs to life and it _wants_ to be a single line (in fact, making it multiline is what becomes practically impossible).

Comment: @HangarRash although it states that property is available starting iOS 15, it was not part of public API in Xcode 13. (that was the reason of complete rewrite of button systems in the project I'm working on). This property is available for public use starting with Xcode 14.3 Beta 1

Comment: @matt if you decide to ignore new configuration API, your code get polluted with bunch of deprecation warnings, which is not nice. Currently multiline behavior was the only limitation for us to adopt the new configuration API

Comment: @ManWithBear None of what I'm suggesting is "deprecated".

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureButton()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureButton()
    }
    
    private func configureButton() {
       // Set the button configuration
       let config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
       config.title = "Custom Button"
       config.baseForegroundColor = .white
       config.baseBackgroundColor = .blue
       config.cornerRadius = 8
       config.titleTextAlignment = .center
    
       // Set the line break mode for the button's text
       config.titleLineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    
       // Apply the configuration to the button
       configuration = config
   }
}
```

Then use like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let customButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 50))
    view.addSubview(customButton)
}
```